# Creating Ellipsis and Keyword Match Up on the Result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a problem on how to make these solution

**First one** is, I want to have "ellipsis(...)" whenever the user input more than 10 characters. Here's my codes Jquery codes

```
$("#input").bind("keypress keydown", function(){
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#results").text($("#input").val());
},0);
```

});

Here's my html tags

```
Enter Character here: <input type="text" id="input">
Search Results: <input type="text" id="search">
<div id="result"></div>
```

**Second one** is, I want to have highlight the words that match on the search input that I've created. Just like in google search. Whenever you've entered a keyword, it will highlight those keyword on the search results.

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/deanilvincent/gm4k3hbe/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would use CSS's `text-overflow` property to add an ellipsis when the text doesn't fit it's container:

```
p {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

But I've demonstrated how it can be done with javascript in the fiddle. I also added an example for your second question:

[Edited fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gm4k3hbe/2/)

Comment: Sir jazZRo. Your jsfiddle is what I'm talking about :D Yeah css can be use but the ellipsis will depends on the size of the container. Thanks a lot sir! God bless! :D